# Overlay div onto td cell using jquery.position upon mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, overlay, position

I have a large table with numbers only and a small font-size, which makes it hard to see. Increasing font-size is not a option, but I want to supply a zoom like effect (without having to use browser zoom) using a simple div overlay upon hovered td cell if it has any content.
The div should be centered on the td cell and the content of the div should be replaced the text content of hovered td cell.

Where is my error ?
*Note: I am using .delegate() instead of .hover() because I already am doing other stuff which require delegate.*

**HTML**

```
<div id="mine"><table border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2">
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td><td></td><td></td><td>5</td></tr>
</table></div>
<div id="your">vale</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#your {
    position: absolute;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mine').delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
      if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        $('#your').position({
          my: "center bottom",
          at: "center top",
          of: this,
          offset: "0 -20", // Place it above td cell
          collision: "none"
        });
        $('#your').clearQueue();
        $('#your').text($(this).text()).fadeIn(200);
      } else {
        $('#your').delay(300).fadeOut(200);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

**Edit** I am seeing `#your` flying all over the place at first run, then the next few hovers it works, but then it begins to pop up all weird places - including outside `#mine`.

Comment: What's your problem with it exactly? I tried it and it works, with the exception that it rapidly fades-in/out when you hover over an item, but the positioning works fine. Is this the problem you're having?

Comment: I was using http://jsfiddle.net/ to test the code, but it didnt work there. Works on my site.. somewhat. See edited code.

Comment: I had that same issue initially, just make sure you're using the most up to date versions of JQuery and UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using an overlay div, which is *larger* than the element it overlays was a bad idea - it had to be somewhere else.
Here is what I ended up doing as splitting up "mouseover" & "mouseleave" was NOT an option, due to other things preformed.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mine').delegate('td', 'mouseover mouseleave', function(e) {
    if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
      if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        var off = $(this).offset();
        $('#your').css({ // Using .position() was buggy. Styles ALWAYS works
          opacity: '', // Remove it if fadeOut didnt finish properly, eg too fast mouse movement
          left: (off.left -14)+'px', // 14 is half of box width
          top: (off.top -20 -37)+'px', // 37 is height of font within box. 20 is to place it above
        });
        $('#your').clearQueue().text($(this).text()).show(); // fadeIn wasnt really needed
      } else {
        $('#your').delay(900).fadeOut(150);  // long delay to allow moving mouse to another cell without box disappearing fast, else fade out fast
      }
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is the flicker that happens, it's because you have it fading out `#your` when you leave the `td`, which you leave the second `#your` appears (because `#your` appears under your mouse cursor at that time since you are hovering directly over the `td`)

Way to fix this is to remove the `mouseleave` from `#mine` and create a separate listener for `mouseleave` specifically for `#your`. So when your mouse leaves `#your` it will fadeOut `#your`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#mine').delegate('td', 'mouseover', function(e) {
    if ($(this).text().length > 0) {
      if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        $('#your').position({
          my: "center",
          at: "center",
          of: e,
          collision: "none"
        });
        $('#your').clearQueue();
        $('#your').text($(this).text()).fadeIn(200);
      }
    }
  });
});

$('#your').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut(200)
});
```

Also, alter your CSS so that `#your` doesn't start out visible.

```
#your {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    width: 40px;
    height: 30px;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid green;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```